# How do I persist the current page/state after closing/reopening a homepage app?

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I have developed a mobile web app using .NET and jQuery Mobile that I plan to be used as a "homepage app" on the iPad. There are certain instances when the user of this app may venture outside of the app while in the middle of doing something (sending/checking email, looking something up on the web, etc), and then coming back to my app (via the multitasking pane, for instance). Currently, every time the homepage app is loaded back up, it reloads the default homepage URL again, causing the app to lose its state.

How can I persist the state of the app in these cases? I was not able to locate anything in the docs about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use Web Storage to save the state on the client. Your site would then read the stored state in and restore it if it exists. See: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

FWIW, you could also do it with cookies, but web storage is *much* easier to work with and is almost universally supported in mobile browsers.

Comment: Great. Thanks! I ended up completing this with cookies since I needed server-side access to the last accessed URL.